# SelectedItem of ContextMenu is null

Tags: c#, binding, contextmenu, selecteditem

I'm trying to get the SelectedItem of a ContextMenu.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}">
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding OCContext}" PreviewMouseDown="ContextMenu_PreviewMouseDown"/>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Delete Item" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        OCContext = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        MyList.Add("Item 1");
        MyList.Add("Item 2");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> OCContext { get; set; }
    public string MySelectedItem { get; set; }

    private void ContextMenu_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuBase s = sender as MenuBase;
        ItemCollection ic = s.Items;
        string MyItem = "";
        MyItem = (string)ic.CurrentItem;
        MyList.Add(MyItem);
        OCContext.Remove(MyItem);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MySelectedItem != null)
        {
            OCContext.Add(MySelectedItem);
            MyList.Remove(MySelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

You can Copy/Paste the code and the program should work.

The program is doing the following:

You can select an item in the ListBox. If you click on "Delete Item", the item will be deleted and added to the ContextMenu. If you click on the ContextMenu-Item, the item should be added again to the ListBox and removed from the ContextMenu. You should be able to do this over and over again...

So the ContextMenu is being binded to a collection. I get the Item with `ic.CurrentItem`.
The problem is that when I delete the item in the ListBox and add it again (by clicking on the item on the ContextMenu), ic.CurrentItem will be null.

Why?

Edit: Solution of Cyphryx is working, but now I'm trying to do the same by using MVVM/Binding:

XAML:

```
<ContextMenu x:Name="MyContext" ContextMenu="{Binding MyContextMenu}" ItemsSource="{Binding OCContext}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _occontext;
    public ObservableCollection<string> OCContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_occontext == null)
                _occontext = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            MyContextMenu.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var str in _occontext)
            {
                var item = new System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem();
                item.Header = str;
                item.Click += Content_MouseLeftButtonUp;
                MyContextMenu.Items.Add(item);
            }

            return _occontext;
        }
        set
        {
            _occontext = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => OCContext);
        }
    }

    private void Content_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem;
        if (s == null) return;
        string ic = s.Header.ToString();
    }

    private System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu _mycontextmenu;
    public System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu MyContextMenu
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mycontextmenu == null)
                _mycontextmenu = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();
            return _mycontextmenu;
        }
        set
        {
            _mycontextmenu = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyContextMenu);
        }
    }
```

`Content_MouseLeftButtonUp` is not being called?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudi, from my knowledge, you cannot assign event handlers to individual objects in bound source.  You can only use the WPF event handlers for the object it is tied to, hence, you'll have to fill the context menu manually, allowing you to add the event handlers at that time. In short, when you add 
`PreviewMouseDown="ContextMenu_PreviewMouseDown"` to you WPF, the handler is assigned to the context menu, but when the binding adds the individual menu items, it does not add that handler to each item, leaving you event handless ;-)  Below is code that will fix this:

WPF

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" Height="Auto" MinHeight="20">
                <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu" Opened="ContextMenu_Opened" />
                </ListBox.ContextMenu>
            </ListBox>
            <Button Content="Delete Item" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    OCContext = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    MyList.Add("Item 1");
    MyList.Add("Item 2");
    InitializeComponent();

}
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<string> OCContext { get; set; }
public string MySelectedItem { get; set; }

private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var str in OCContext)
    {
        var item = new MenuItem();
        item.Header = str;
        item.Click += Content_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        ContextMenu.Items.Add(item);
    }
}

private void Content_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = sender as MenuItem;
    if (s == null) return;
    var ic = s.Header.ToString();

    MyList.Add(ic);
    OCContext.Remove(ic);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MySelectedItem != null)
    {
        OCContext.Add(MySelectedItem);
        MyList.Remove(MySelectedItem);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Cyphryx

Comment: Yes, this helped me a lot! :). I just couldn't find any other event than `ContextMenu_PreviewMouseDown` (didn't see MouseLeftButton ...). Thanks! And also thanks for making clear why it didn't work.

Comment: Is this also possible with binding? I actually want to do this with MVVM and put this in the ViewModel. I'm assigning the `var ic` to the ViewModel by using `ViewModelLocator.Main.MyValue = ic`.